# Area common to $n$ circles and a rectangle

Tags: definite-integrals, circles, area, rectangles

I am provided with the radii and coordinates of the centers of $n$
circles and the bottom-left and top-right coordinates of a
rectangle.

How can I find out the area that is inscribed within the area of the
rectangle by the circles?

Comment: similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391601/area-of-intersection-of-a-circle-with-a-rectangle)

Comment: Sounds like a question ripe for approximations

Comment: There will be multiple formulas depending on cases (the shape of the intersection).

Comment: I just found a mistake in my question and edited it. Could you please have a look at it now?

Comment: Take first the case $n=1$...

Comment: Could you please show me some way to approach the problem?